# DialogFragment back button closes to main activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

I can't figure out why pressing the hardware back button (or the dialog OK button for that matter) doesn't return me to the initial DialogFragment at times.

I have a DeductionListDialog fragment that is called from the options menu of MainActivity as such:

```
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    ...
    case R.id.action_deduction_list:
        DialogFragment newFragment = new DeductionListDialog();
        newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

DeductionListDialog then has a couple of onClickListeners within its onCreateDialog method:

```
        // the listview that holds the deduction list
    ListView listview = (ListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        // set a short click listener
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // create a new dialog fragment
            DialogFragment deduction_specifics = new DeductionSpecificsDialog();

            // / bundle database row so we can get the correct info
            // for our specific listing
            Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
            arguments.putLong("database_row", id);
            deduction_specifics.setArguments(arguments);
            deduction_specifics.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
        }
    });
    // set the long click listener
    listview.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

        // on long click we want to open the edit fragment
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            DialogFragment deduction_edit = new DeductionEditFragment();
            Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
            arguments.putLong("database_id", id);
            deduction_edit.setArguments(arguments);
            deduction_edit.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
            /*Intent deduction_edit_intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DeductionEditActivity.class);
            deduction_edit_intent.putExtra("database_id", id);
            startActivity(deduction_edit_intent);*/
            return true;
        }
    });
```

When the listview onItemClick & onItemLongClick listeners are clicked, another dialog pops up with various pieces of information. When I press the back button, or the dialog's OK button, I return to the initial DeductionListDialog fragment as expected.

The DeductionListDialog also has within its onCreateDialog method:

```
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
...
        alertDialogBuilder.setView(view);
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Deductions: ");
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Long press to update or delete");
    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
               // User clicked OK button
               dialog.dismiss();
           }
       });
    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
               // User clicked Add button
                DialogFragment deduction_edit = new DeductionEditFragment();
                Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
                deduction_edit.setArguments(arguments);
                deduction_edit.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");

               /*Intent deduction = new Intent(getActivity(), DeductionEditActivity.class);
               startActivity(deduction);*/
           }
       });
```

When I click the "Add" button, a new DeductionEditFragment is created. When I click back (or the dialog's cancel & accept buttons) I expect the view to go back to the original DeductionListDialog fragment, but clicks simply result in the fragment closing back to the MainActivity.

1) Why is this the case as I'd like to learn how to prevent this in the future.
2) What's the quickest way to resolve this issue?
3) What's the 'proper' way of resolving this issue if differenct from #2?

A pastebin of the entire three classes (DeductionListDialog, DeductionEditDialog, DeductionSpecificsDialog) can be found here: http://pastebin.com/AJQ6KCEN
Thanks all.

Comment: AFIK, dialogs are created on basis of activity context, so pressing the cancels button cancels the dialog from activity context.

Comment: This doesn't explain why the back function from one dialog returns to the calling dialog whereas the back function from another dialog closes all dialogs to the calling activity.